# Adding Message before Magento Payment redirect

Tags: magento-1.8, payment-gateway, redirect

I've developed a new payment module for Magento.It works well but the redirect to the gateway takes about 3o seconds.
I will like to add a message, "please wait while you are redirected to make payment". How can I do that?

The redirect is from the checkout process

Below is my **redirect.phtml** form

```
<form name="mygatewayform" method="post" action="https://mygateway.com/Payment.aspx">
<input type="hidden" name="orderid" value="<?php echo $orderId; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="grandtotal" value="<?php echo $_order->getBaseGrandTotal(); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="mercId" value="somenumber" />
<input type="hidden" name="prod" value="Ordered Products" />
<input type="hidden" name="amt" value="<?php echo $_order->getBaseGrandTotal(); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $customer->getEmail(); ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit how the redirection works? Is there an intermediary page? or directly from the checkout process?

Answer (score 1):

Well....just add this above the `<form>` tag (or below it, or inside it).

```
<div>please wait while you are redirected to make payment</div>
```